# Codeigniter,The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Code :

```
 $this->db->select('baslik');
   $this->db->from('sayfa');
   $this->db->like('baslik', $baslik);
   $this->db->get();
   $query1 = $this->db->last_query();



 $this->db->select('isim');
   $this->db->from('bebek');
   $this->db->like('isim', $baslik);
   $this->db->get();
   $query2 = $this->db->last_query();
   $query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION  ".$query2);
   return $query->result_array();
```

My problem;in select field 2. the data gives error when
"The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"
for example:

```
$this->db->select('baslik,seo');
```

"**seo**"

How can I solve this problem thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use union of 2 queries you should have `SAME` number of columns in select.

If you have different number of columns then, in the query with less number of columns you have to set the additional column to null to take up for empty space.

Try this:

```
   $this->db->select('baslik,seo');
   $this->db->from('sayfa');
   $this->db->like('baslik', $baslik);
   $this->db->get();
   $query1 = $this->db->last_query();

   $this->db->select('isim,null as seo');
   $this->db->from('bebek');
   $this->db->like('isim', $baslik);
   $this->db->get();
   $query2 = $this->db->last_query();
   $query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION  ".$query2);
   return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: not working  error code:Unknown column 'null' in 'field list'